# Combine Excel cells if value is within certain ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use concatenate to combine certain cells if value in others cells meet certain criteria. What would be the best way to go about it? I've been trying concatenate + if statement but cannot figure it out.

Example below:

[image: Example]

Comment: A couple of questions: is this problem limited to 3 cells? You can combine if/concatenate to join matching cells but it makes for an awkward (and not especially scalable) formula. Also, separating the terms consistently (e.g. with ', ' between two names but not after the last one) will make a mess. How are you hoping that would be handled?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the questions - the problem will apply to about 30 cells, the ones added are just an example. Anything would be fine to separate the names.

Comment: Yikes, that's a lot of concatenating. You should probably edit your question to include that detail. I'm not sure whether my answer would work in such circumstances as there are limits to how long a formula can be — plus it gets unwieldy with too many cells.

Comment: If you don't mind adding a row in which each cell checks for a match, then it would be fairly simple, e.g. in cell A3, put something like `IF(AND(A2<1.3,A2>0),A1&", ","")`. Do the same for B3:Z3 (or wherever). Then, in your concatenating cell, you could put `LEFT(CONCATENATE(A3:Z3),LEN(CONCATENATE(A3:Z3))-2)`. This would be much simpler to maintain and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your top six cells are A1:C2, then a formula such as this would concatenate the matching names in A1:C1.

```
CONCATENATE(IF(AND(A2<1.3,A2>0),A1&", ",""),IF(AND(B2<1.3,B2>0),B1&", ",""),IF(AND(C2<1.3,C2>0),C1,""))
```

In essence, what it does is ask if (for each of cells A2:C2) whether they are within the specified range.

To break it down… if A2 meets both conditions, then return cell A1 followed by comma space. If it doesn't meet both conditions, return nothing. This is done for each cell pair. Then all three results are concatenated.

```
IF(AND(A2<1.3,A2>0),A1&", ","")
```

But this creates a problem as the last matching item is also followed by the comma/space.

To deal at least partially with this, you can use the `left` and `len` functions to exclude the last two characters. Here, it gets the length of the resulting text and returns everything but the final two characters.

```
LEFT(CONCATENATE(IF(AND(A2<1.3,A2>0),A1&", ",""),IF(AND(B2<1.3,B2>0),B1&", ",""),IF(AND(C2<1.3,C2>0),C1&", ","")),LEN(CONCATENATE(IF(AND(A2<1.3,A2>0),A1&", ",""),IF(AND(B2<1.3,B2>0),B1&", ",""),IF(AND(C2<1.3,C2>0),C1&", ","")))-2)
```

Of course, if none of your numbers fall within the range, then you'll get an error. That could presumably be addressed with an if/iserror combination.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper row, then enter the following array formula to show the value is between 0 & 1.3.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A1:$C1,0,SMALL(IF(($A$2:$C$2<1.3)*($A$2:$C$2>0),COLUMN($A:$C),4^8),COLUMN(A$1))),"")`

[image]

As the results are in Row 7, then we could use the formula `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$7:$7)` to get the last result.

[image]